# How to add liveData to MPandroidchart

Tags: android, android-fragments, viewmodel, mpandroidchart, android-livedata

I've created a line chart using the MPandroidchart library and want to fill it with user input saved in room and stored in a liveData list. I've made the chart and implemented the viewModel class, but I'm unsure on how to add the liveData as the chart data.

Graph.java (fragment where the chart is displayed)

```
public class Graph extends Fragment {

    public Graph() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    private LineChart mChart;
    private InputViewModel mInputViewModel;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_graph, container, false);


        Log.e("create","graph oncreate method reached");

        //initialize chart
        mChart = view.findViewById(R.id.chart);
        //set description
        Description description = new Description();
        description.setText("Blood glucose levels");
        mChart.setDescription(description);
        //set description if no data is available
        mChart.setNoDataText("No Data Available. Add a blood glucose level input to see your graph");
        //enable touch gestures
        mChart.setTouchEnabled(true);
        //enable scaling and dragging
        mChart.setDragEnabled(true);
        mChart.setScaleEnabled(true);
        //draw background grid
        mChart.setDrawGridBackground(true);
        //draw x-axis
        XAxis xAxis = mChart.getXAxis();
        xAxis.setEnabled(false);
        // setting position to TOP and INSIDE the chart
        xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.TOP_INSIDE);
        //  setting text size for our axis label
        xAxis.setTextSize(10f);
        xAxis.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        // to draw axis line
        xAxis.setDrawAxisLine(true);
        xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);

        YAxis yAxis = mChart.getAxisLeft();
        // setting the count of Y-axis label's
        yAxis.setLabelCount(12, false);
        yAxis.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        yAxis.setPosition(YAxis.YAxisLabelPosition.OUTSIDE_CHART);
        yAxis.setDrawGridLines(true);

        //add upper limit line
        LimitLine upper = new LimitLine(8, "Above target range");
        upper.setLineColor(Color.parseColor("#bb2d2d"));
        upper.setLineWidth(3f);
        upper.enableDashedLine(10f, 10f, 0f);
        upper.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        upper.setTextSize(9f);
        yAxis.addLimitLine(upper);
        //add lower limit line
        LimitLine lower = new LimitLine(4, "Below target range");
        lower.setLineColor(Color.parseColor("#2c8ec7"));
        lower.setLineWidth(3f);
        lower.enableDashedLine(10f, 10f, 0f);
        lower.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        lower.setTextSize(9f);
        yAxis.addLimitLine(lower);

        yAxis.setDrawLimitLinesBehindData(true);

        mChart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
        mChart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);

        // add data
        setData();

        mChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mChart.invalidate();



        return view;
    }

    private void setData() {

        final ArrayList<Entry> values = new ArrayList<>();
        //implement viewModel and liveData
        mInputViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(InputViewModel.class);
        mInputViewModel.getAllInput1s().observe(this, new Observer<List<Input1>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable final List<Input1> input1s) {

            }
        });
        values.add(new Entry(0, (float) 4.8));

        Log.e("set", "method reached");

        LineDataSet set1;
        if (mChart.getData() != null &&
                mChart.getData().getDataSetCount() > 0) {
            set1 = (LineDataSet) mChart.getData().getDataSetByIndex(0);
            set1.setValues(values);
            mChart.getData().notifyDataChanged();
            mChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            set1 = new LineDataSet(values, "Blood Glucose Levels");
            set1.setDrawIcons(false);
            set1.setLineWidth(4f);
            set1.setCircleRadius(5f);
            set1.setDrawCircleHole(false);
            set1.setValueTextSize(10f);
            set1.setFormLineWidth(1f);
            set1.setFormSize(15.f);
            set1.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            set1.setCircleColor(Color.BLACK);

        }
        ArrayList<ILineDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
        dataSets.add(set1);
        final LineData data = new LineData(dataSets);
        mChart.setData(data);
        mChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mChart.invalidate();

        //implement viewModel and liveData
        mInputViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(InputViewModel.class);
        mInputViewModel.getAllInput1s().observe(this, new Observer<List<Input1>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable final List<Input1> input1s) {
                //*****insert livedata here?*****//

            }
        });

        mChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mChart.invalidate();

    }
    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        Log.e("resume", "onResume reached");
        setData();
    }
}
```

Tabbed.java (base activity of the fragment)

```
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        mInputViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(InputViewModel.class);
        //only add if there is a new input
        Log.e("result1","onActivityResult tabbed reacher");
        if (requestCode == INPUT_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            //retrieve input from room database
            Input1 input1 = new Input1(data.getStringExtra(input.EXTRA_REPLY));
            //insert the inputs into the view model of the recyclerView
            mInputViewModel.insert(input1);
}
```

InputViewModel.java

```
public class InputViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    private InputRepository mRepository;
    private LiveData<List<Input1>> mAllInput1s;
    public InputViewModel (Application application) {
        super(application);
        mRepository = new InputRepository(application);
        mAllInput1s = mRepository.getAllInput1s();
    }
    LiveData<List<Input1>> getAllInput1s() {return mAllInput1s;}
    void insert(Input1 input1) {mRepository.insert(input1);}
}
```

I just need a way to set the data of the chart as the LiveData

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You mean you data binding to set up the data to the chart?

Comment: @LiemVo yeah, so that the data in the chart is the liveData